# Can I create same index for 2 buckets in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am new to couchbase and I have a requirement to create same index (same index create statement) on 2 buckets. Can I use same index name for 2 buckets?

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this in Couchbase Server 6.5.1:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_foo ON `bucket1` (bar,baz,qux);
CREATE INDEX ix_foo ON `bucket2` (bar,baz,qux);
```

And yes, it is allowed.